# E: Unable to locate package windbind Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: playonlinux

In Ubuntu 16.04 below was working fine and able to install windbind

```
# apt-get install playonlinux windbind -y
```

But in 18.04 by installing same getting below response

```
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package windbind
```

And I am unable to install office because I couldn't found windbind.

Comment: Are you mistyping? Is `winbind - service to resolve user and group information from Windows NT servers` what you really mean?

Comment: I am trying to install office on ubuntu, 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vf8zr096mYQ
but stuck at windbind installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not read correctly - the package that is installed in that video is `winbind`, **not** `windbind`.

So `sudo apt install playonlinux winbind` will do what you have seen in that video.

Comment: Ops yes, it was typo due to copy paste, will mark it resolved, thanks